# MySQL Stored Procedure with Multiple Tables

Tags: mysql

I want to show all the records of my `items` table. But some quantity need to be a negative value.

```
BEGIN 
    SET @ItemId1 = (SELECT ItemId FROM items);

    SELECT 
        SUM(ROUND(Quantity)) 
    FROM (
        SELECT
            COALESCE(SUM(od.Quantity),0) as Quantity
        FROM sts as T1
        LEFT JOIN orderset_details as od 
            ON T1.OrdersetId = od.OrdersetId
        WHERE od.ItemId = @ItemId1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 
            COALESCE(SUM(od.Quantity),0) as Quantity
        FROM drs as T2
        LEFT JOIN orderset_details as od 
            ON T2.OrdersetId = od.OrdersetId
        WHERE od.ItemId = @ItemId1
        UNION ALL  
        SELECT 
            COALESCE(
                SUM(
                    IF(r.AddsToStock = '1', od.Quantity, 0 - od.Quantity)
                ),0
            ) as Quantity
        FROM stockadjustment as T3
        LEFT JOIN reason as r 
            ON r.ReasonId = T3.ReasonId
        LEFT JOIN orderset_details as od 
            ON T3.OrdersetId = od.OrdersetId 
        WHERE od.ItemId = @ItemId1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 
            COALESCE(
                SUM(
                    IF(T4.OrdersetId = od.OrdersetId, 0 - od.Quantity, -1 * od.Quantity)
                ),0
            ) as Quantity
        FROM issueslip as T4
        LEFT JOIN orderset_details as od 
            ON T4.OrdersetId = od.OrdersetId 
        WHERE od.ItemId = @ItemId1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 
            COALESCE(
                SUM(
                    IF(T4.OrdersetId = od.OrdersetId, 0 - od.Quantity, -1 * od.Quantity)
                ),0
            ) as Quantity
        FROM invoice as T4
        LEFT JOIN orderset_details as od 
            ON T4.OrdersetId = od.OrdersetId
        WHERE od.ItemId = @ItemId1
    ) as t;
END
```

This code got an error `MySQL said: #1242 -Subquery returns more than 1 row`.

I want all the quantity of every item to be shown. Thats why I have @ItemId1 to get all the `ItemId from items`. How Can I do that?

Comment: Check the first line. You're selecting multiple values

Comment: Yep its auto_increment value so no duplicates

Comment: Yes, but you're trying to assign multiple values to a scalar.

Comment: What should I do then?

Answer (score 1):

You should group by ItemId.
Try this

```
SELECT 
    ItemId, SUM(ROUND(Quantity)) 
FROM (
    SELECT
        od.ItemId, COALESCE(SUM(od.Quantity),0) as Quantity
    FROM sts as T1
    LEFT JOIN orderset_details as od 
        ON T1.OrdersetId = od.OrdersetId
   -- WHERE od.ItemId = @ItemId1
    GROUP BY od.ItemId
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        od.ItemId, COALESCE(SUM(od.Quantity),0) as Quantity
    FROM drs as T2
    LEFT JOIN orderset_details as od 
        ON T2.OrdersetId = od.OrdersetId
    --WHERE od.ItemId = @ItemId1
    GROUP BY od.ItemId
    UNION ALL  
    SELECT 
      od.ItemId,
        COALESCE(
            SUM(
                IF(r.AddsToStock = '1', od.Quantity, 0 - od.Quantity)
            ),0
        ) as Quantity
    FROM stockadjustment as T3
    LEFT JOIN reason as r 
        ON r.ReasonId = T3.ReasonId
    LEFT JOIN orderset_details as od 
        ON T3.OrdersetId = od.OrdersetId 
    --WHERE od.ItemId = @ItemId1
    GROUP BY od.ItemId
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
       od.ItemId,
        COALESCE(
            SUM(
                IF(T4.OrdersetId = od.OrdersetId, 0 - od.Quantity, -1 * od.Quantity)
            ),0
        ) as Quantity
    FROM issueslip as T4
    LEFT JOIN orderset_details as od 
        ON T4.OrdersetId = od.OrdersetId 
    --WHERE od.ItemId = @ItemId1
    GROUP BY od.ItemId
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        od.ItemId
        COALESCE(
            SUM(
                IF(T4.OrdersetId = od.OrdersetId, 0 - od.Quantity, -1 * od.Quantity)
            ),0
        ) as Quantity
    FROM invoice as T4
    LEFT JOIN orderset_details as od 
        ON T4.OrdersetId = od.OrdersetId
    --WHERE od.ItemId = @ItemId1
    GROUP BY od.ItemId
) as t
GROUP BY ItemId;
```

Comment: it worked but ... `Showing rows 0 - 29 ( 2,890 total, Query took 137.2460 sec)` is there any other way?

Comment: Check the explain plan. Are there good indexes on your tables?

Comment: and btw from what you did `GROUP BY ItemId` make it work but the ItemId should be coming from the `items` tables

Comment: Start here: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/78555/best-practices-to-follow-with-database-indexes